# How to stop auto program raspberry pi

Tags: boot-issues

I bought a raspberry and I defined it to run a auto program in the boot by changing the rc.local.
The problem is that the program is running and ctr+c doesn't work.
There is a way to stop the program during it is running?
There is a way to edit rc.local and fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, edit rc.local to remove that entry again. However that is not going to stop the running instance of that program, it just prevents that it is started again after the next reboot.

To stop that program do the following:

Run `ps aux | grep <your-program's-name-here>` (the listed example used `ps aux | grep mopidy`). You'll get a result like this

```
pi   280  0.0 19.4 218896 146148 ?       Sl   Apr09   0:54 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/mopidy
pi 10052  0.0  0.0   2644   500 pts/0    S+   21:26   0:00 grep mopidy
```

The number after pi (which is the user running the program) is the so called PID - a unique number identifying the running program. Use that number to issue this command to stop it from running: `kill -TERM <PID>` or if it still resists `kill -KILL <PID>`. In the example above that translates to `kill -TERM 280` (see `man kill`).

If installed you might also want to use `killall` which kills processes by name (see `man killall`).

Comment: Try Ctrl + Alt + F1 to F6 for another virtual console to enter the commands.

Comment: Just in case, do you know how can I reach to rc.local?

Comment: Open `/etc/rc.local` in your favourite command line based text editor, e.g. `nano /etc/rc.local`

Comment: ... and by the way, check https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/ for hints and tricks, e.g. concerning the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend this as a guide to creating an automatically running daemon which you can start and stop from the commandline:

http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/07/getting-a-python-script-to-run-in-the-background-as-a-service-on-boot/

It's a simple matter of cutting and pasting the script and 3 tiny modifications.

Comment: Come on, that response is totally worth a "useful".