# Turn off screen reader in Raspberry Pi OS?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

This is a fun one: somehow, the screen reader accessibility setting has been turned on in my Raspberry Pi OS environment. I can't figure out how to turn it off! Other than turning off all audio, the only solution I've found is to uninstall the `eSpeak` module and supporting libraries, which is obviously not the ideal solution.

I've tried googling around but found only tutorials on how to *install* the text-to-speech.

Anyone know how this gets turned on and how one turns it off?

Comment: `sudo apt purge orca`

Comment: Thanks. That just removes a package. (I don't think it's using Orca; I think it's using eSpeak.) Anyway, I'm hoping to actually turn off the setting so that I can keep the packages installed but not have the UI constantly reading to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hold down the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key and press the <kbd>S</kbd> key.

It should say Speech Enabled/Disabled.

Comment: Welcome Dave.  If you look at the top of the editor interface there is a toolbar with a **?** on the right that links to help about how to use the interface.

Answer (score 6):

`espeak` is a speech synthesizer, it transforms text into sound but will not grab text from your screen and read it aloud. This is a function of screen reader. You have to find out which one you have and uninstall or disable it.

In case you got `orca` for a screen reader, it can be deactivated by removing `/etc/xdg/autostart/orca-autostart.desktop`.

Comment: In the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/orca-autostart.desktop` I commented out the line `Exec=orca`, now it looks like this `#Exec=orca`. It worked, the annunciation stopped after reboot of  `Raspbian buster, Release 10` system.

Answer (score 1):

Just uncheck orca from the recommended software area....it'll remove the orca packages for you

Answer (score 0):

You might try to kill a specific process/es as described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46015/how-to-stop-auto-p). Please try and check if that helps. I checked my Raspberry Pi OS and **orca** is not installed by default.