# My Raspi speaker is saying everything I write

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-os

Something strange is happening with my Raspi speaker.

Everything I do in Raspbian is repeated by my speaker.

For example, when I type "ls" in my terminal, it says "ls" and then tells me all the folders found in the directory.

How can I turn off this weird behavior?

Comment: This might help https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121486/turn-off-screen-reader-in-raspberry-pi-os

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn off screen reader in Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121486/turn-off-screen-reader-in-raspberry-pi-os)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove orca
sudo apt-get remove gnome-orca
killall orca
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more descriptive and explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *text to speech* program

`sudo apt purge espeak`

or the *screen reader* program

`sudo apt purge orca`

Comment: It should be enough to remove orca (screen reader) since espeak is just a "text to speech" program that orca is using.

Comment: OK. Got it! I just realized that too :)